# Vertical centering in a div

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I am having a problem making my logo and links align vertically. I have tried to achieve this using inline block and `vertical-align` set to `middle` but it didn't work.

I know I can achieve this using flex box. But I don't want to use flex box. And if I must use flex, is flex box better in achieving proper alignment?

Please any help will be appreciated.

```css
.header {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.logo,
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">XCode</div>
  <ul>
    <li>Account settings</li>
    <li>Profile</li>
    <li>Logout</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I vertically center text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-do-i-vertically-center-text-with-css)

Comment: it is not the same question/problems

Answer (score 3):

In many browsers, the `ul` element comes with default top and bottom margins.

*Chrome:*

[image]

[image]

Those margins are throwing off the vertical centering. Just remove them.

```css
.header {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.logo, ul {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul {
  margin: 0; /* NEW */
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">XCode</div>
  <ul>
    <li>Account settings</li>
    <li>Profile</li>
    <li>Logout</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: got its. Thanks alot perfect

Answer (score 1):

In some browsers, the `<ul>` element has margin by default.

Try

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
}
```

to remove the default margins.

Answer (score 1):

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin:0 auto;
}
margin:0 auto; will help you to set the ul element in vertically align.
```

```css
.header {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.logo,
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin:0 auto;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">XCode</div>
  <ul>
    <li>Account settings</li>
    <li>Profile</li>
    <li>Logout</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might check out Bulma, specifically their [Level](https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/level/) attribute. This uses flexbox in the background, but you don't have to learn it- just the easy-to-use classes!

```
<!-- Main container -->
<nav class="level">

    <!-- Left side -->
    <div class="level-left">
        <div class="level-item">
            <p class="subtitle is-5">Content</p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Right side -->
    <div class="level-right"> 
        <p class="level-item">More Content</p> 
        <p class="level-item"><a class="button is-success">New</a></p>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

margin: 0; will help you.

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n0o915w3/1/